# Error browsing simple products 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, php-7

I can't open simple products.. keep getting error as below,
tried disabling Temando_shipping..

no joy.. any ideas to resolve?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Temando\Shipping\Model\Source\PackagingType does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Temando\Shipping\Model\Source\PackagingType does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:49]
2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36]
5 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:641]
6 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php:1181]
```

Comment: Having a same issue, after rolling back from 2.3.3 update to 2.3.2

Comment: can you please enable of Temando shipping module after flush and check

Answer (score 8):

You can remove generated directory using this command, because you've disabled that module but some code which is generated in generated/code/ directory which is still available there. So you need to remove that first.

> rm -rf generated/

and then just run upgrade command if you are using developer mode. Otherwise run all deployment commands there and then check again.

If you're using developer mode in magento then run below command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Otherwise run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**If that will not work then you can try this steps...**

Go to your database and search `eav_attribute` table, there may be some attributes available which are using **Temando** model classes there.

So you can search in this fields **source_model** like **Temando**

You can see this output :

[image]

and then remove that Temando attribute there or you can set **NULL** value for that attribute or you can `unassign` all three Temando Shipping module's attribute from backend **(Store > Attributes > Attribute Set)** and just clear cache.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: when I run below commands Temando folder is recreated in generated folder & same error php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Can you please run this command and check your module disabled properly ? **php bin/magento mo:d Temando_Shipping**.  If your module properly disabled there then you'll get this message **"No modules were changed."**.

Comment: Otherwise try to enable that module first and run this command to disable that module. **php bin/magento mo:d Temando_Shipping --clear-static-content**

Comment: still same error..

Comment: you're getting that error when you run compile command from console ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, that may be help you.

Comment: Replacing source_model column values where it contains Temando at eav_attribute fixed my problem. I just don't get it, why open source Magento framework trying to force us to these useless, nothing but the trouble, lame modules.

Comment: are you still getting same error @Nathan ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove `ts_` prefixed attributes from `Default` attribute set (`Store / Attributes / Attribute Set`):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do with below command :

**rename your "generated" directory in root..**.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Than check...

Comment: thanks will try, as soon as I rename though another 'generated' folder is created & .htaccess is not regenerated inside the folder

Comment: The temando folder is created inside the generated folder when the php bin/magento setup:di:compile command is run

Comment: Still same error